# hide div in aspx page and show div in aspx.vb page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have following code in aspx page:

```
<div id="a" runat="server" style="display:block;">
abc
</div>
```

I am trying to show the div in code like this:

```
a.Visible = True
```

But this is not working. Can anyone suggest how to do this without using any scripting language?

Answer (score 2):

You are missing doube quotes after runat Server. It should be like this..

```
<div id="a" runat="server" style="display:block;">
   abc
</div>
```

Or in code Behind to hide the div

```
a.Style.Add("display","none")
```

in code Behind to show the div

```
a.Style.Add("display","block")
```

Comment: I tried using: display:none; on aspx page and a..Style.Add("display","block") on aspx.vb page. But still not working

Answer (score 2):

A div with `runat=server` becomes a [HtmlGenericControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx) on serverside. This has the [Visible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx)-property as every server-control. So you can hide it on serverside. But that means on clientside it won't get rendered at all.

If you instead want it to be rendered invisibly, add the Style`display:none`:

```
a.Style.Add("display","none")
```

Then you can also switch the visibility on clientside.

Apart from that your tag is malformed, change

```
runat="server
```

to

```
runat="server"
```

Comment: i tried using display:none; and a.Visible = True. But it is not showing the div even now.

Comment: Is the div inside another container control which is `Visible=false`? Controls inherit the visible property from their parents.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a.Attributes.Add("style", "display:block;");
```

Mode details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7512d0d0(v=vs.71).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx

Comment: I dont understand try this where? I am already blocking the div in aspx page. I want to un-block it on aspx.vb page. Why would i block it again?

Comment: Then just toggle it: a.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");

Comment: I've updated my answer, including a link to the Visible property. Your question is vague - can you show the code-behind snippet where you're setting this property?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div id="a"  runat="server"  style="visibility:hidden"  >
 </div>
```

you can try : hidden in code vb.net

```
a.Attributes("style") = "visibility:hidden"
```

you can try : visible

```
a.Attributes("style") = "visibility:visible"
```

thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
a.Style.Add("display", "block")
```

for visible

```
a.Style.Add("display", "none")
```

for hide

Comment: Sorry.. 
a.Style.Add("display", "none") 'For Hide